# cannot get integer value in jsp page

Tags: java, jsp

I am sending values from HTML page to JSP page, but I am unable to use integers. What's the correct code?
My HTML page:

```
<body>
    <form action="salvoCadastro.jsp" method="post">
        <label>Portugues</label>
        <input type="text" name="portuguesinp">
        <label>English</label>
        <input type="text" name="englishinp">
        <label>Funcao Gramatical</label>
        <input type="text" name="funcgraminp">
        <label>Synonimos existentes</label>
    <!--<input type="text" name="nsyninp">  -->
        <input type="submit" value="cadastrar"> 
    </form>
```

My JSP page:

```
<body>
<%
    String sportugues = request.getParameter("portuguesinp");
    String senglish = request.getParameter("englishinp");
    String sfuncgram = request.getParameter("funcgraminp");
    Integer snsyn = request.getParameter("nsyninp");  // snsyn must be integer

    Usuario usu = new Usuario();
    usu.setPortugues(sportugues);
    usu.setEnglish(senglish);
    usu.setFuncgram(sfuncgram);
    usu.setNsyn(snsyn); // --> how receive Integer type??

    UsuarioDao usudDao = new UsuarioDao();
    usudDao.cadastro(usu);
%>
```

Comment: In your html page "<input type="text" name="nsyninp">" is commented. I that's the reason its happening. @Isaac

Comment: Integer snsyn=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("nsyninp"));

Answer (score 0):

Besides what `@Sanjay Kumaar` suggested in the comments, that your html element is commented out, I also think that you should parse the parameter to Integer, since `request.getParameter(...)` will return a `String`.

```
...
Integer snsyn = Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("nsyninp"));
...
```

If you really want to enforce the user to input a number for your `nsyninp` field, and make sure you don't get any exceptions when converting from `String` to `Integer`, I would also change the input type to `number`, like this:

```
<input type="number" name="nsyninp">
```